# Question regarding congruence notation

Tags: group-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

I have a question regarding notation in modular arithmetic and congruence classes.

I am used to the notation 
 $a \equiv b$ $(\mod n)$; it simply means n divides a-b

But I've seen a similar notation in the context of groups (old fashioned one I believe) where the n is replaced by a subgroup and that got me slightly confused. Here it is:

If G is a group, a,b elements in G and P a subgroup of G, then what is the exact meaning of

$a \equiv b$ $(\mod P)$ ? Is it equivalent to $ap_1$=$bp_2$ for some $p_1$,$p_2$ in P?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: It means $a-b\in P$, or $ab^{-1}\in P$, depending on how you write your group operation.